# Why does clang++ remove constructor imports from binary?

Tags: c++, linux, clang, linker-errors, reverse-engineering

Today I found strange clang behaviour with constructors. When g++ exports `_ZN14string_wrapperC1EPcm` and `_ZN14string_wrapperC2EPcm` constructors. Clang exports only `_ZN14string_wrapperC2EPcm` and my injected library can't resolve symbol at runtime.

**Note: `-rdynamic` tells the compiler to export all symbols from the binary file. Therefore, symbols are linked at runtime. What's why my code doesn't have declarations of this function.** (see injector.cpp)

Please advise me how to fix the runtime error. I guess need something like import library from windows. The point is that need to tell the linker that the symbols are declared in my `./output/binary` file. Now it's marked as UND (undefined) and would resolved in runtime.

```sh
$ readelf -Ws output/injector.so | grep _ZN

     2: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN14string_wrapper5printEv
     3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN14string_wrapperC1EPcm
```

binary.cpp:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

class string_wrapper {
private:
    char *data;
    size_t size;
public:
    string_wrapper(char *data, size_t size) : data(data), size(size) {}

    void print() {
        printf("%s\n", data);
    }
};

int main() {
    char data[] = "regular string from this executable";
    string_wrapper string = string_wrapper(data, sizeof(data));
    string.print();

    return 0;
}
```

injector.cpp:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

class string_wrapper {
private:
    char *data;
    size_t size;
public:
    string_wrapper(char *data, size_t size);

    void print();
};

__attribute__((constructor))
static void injector_init() {
    puts("injected into process");

    char data[] = "custom string from injector.so";
    string_wrapper string = string_wrapper(data, sizeof(data));
    string.print();
}
```

Makefile:

```
all: targets binary injector run
targets:
    mkdir -p output
binary:
    clang++ -rdynamic binary.cpp -o output/binary
injector:
    clang++ -fPIC -shared injector.cpp -o output/injector.so
run:
    LD_PRELOAD=./output/injector.so ./output/binary
```

```
$ make

mkdir -p output
clang++ -rdynamic binary.cpp -o output/binary
clang++ -frewrite-imports -fPIC -shared injector.cpp -o output/injector.so
LD_PRELOAD=./output/injector.so ./output/binary
injected into process
./output/binary: symbol lookup error: ./output/injector.so: undefined symbol: _ZN14string_wrapperC1EPcm
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Error 127
```

Comment: Your code violates One Definition Rule because the two definitions of `string_wrapper` are not identical. The behaviour is undefined. Put your class definition in a header file and `#include` it in both sources.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. thanks, but it's just an example. Also, I usually have not source code of the `binary.cpp` and this headers would be reverse engineered.

Comment: I cannot tell you what's wrong with code I cannot see. If you have a problem with some other code, please post that other code. If you have a problem with reverse engineering something, please ask a question about reverse engineering.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. no, this question is more related to linker errors. Limitations is inability to change compilation flags for binary file. Only injector library can be touched.

Comment: Please state your limitation and everything else you might find important in the question itself. Anyway, `string_wrapper` constructor is not exported because it does not exist as a separate symbol. It's inline. You cannot do much about it.